# PyInstaller input text not showing

Tags: python, pycharm, pyinstaller

Ive finished my Python Projekt an tried Pyinstaller.But there is a big Problem, my whole input text does not get displayed in the finished console.
But in the PyCharm console the input text gets displayed.

```
confirmation = input("Are you sure? J/N: ")
```

Something like this is only an empty line in my Command Line.

Ive already tried

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
pyinstaller --console main.py
```

But that does not work

I executed this command in the PyCharm termin, but i dont think this is a problem?
I hope you can help me :D

Comment: you need to print it

Comment: hmm okay i will try. Thanks. Edit: Does not work for me :/